# How do I find the mouse's position on the canvas when the canvas has a % width on it?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

So, I know a similar question has been asked before but this is asking for something slightly different: My canvas has a `x%` CSS style width and a `y` width. Nothing is constant, but an example would be:

```js
canvas.style.width;
// Returns: 60%
canvas.width;
// Returns: 800
```

So, I need to figure out how to find the X on the canvas where the mouse is (the position should be in the canvas' width so for example, if you were to click on a coordinate it would draw that coordinate on the canvas).

How can I do this knowing that `1px` of my screen does not equal `1px` of my canvas? I know how to evaluate the Y once I get the equation for the X.

Comment: You are in the "**When Element and Bitmap are of different sizes**" case.

Comment: Thx I've spent hours looking and trying solutions

Comment: Yes, you need to multiply by this ratio `/`->`*`

Comment: oh sorry i misread thx

Comment: It does: https://jsfiddle.net/pqswn6om/

Comment: @Kaiido no i said it did work, its fine. thx